# Screen Capture program in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, image, exception, timer, image-capture

I had created an application that captures the screenshot of desktop screen. It works very well with button I have used in form. But now I want to make that thing works automatically using timers but whenever I try to run program `NullReferenceException` occur can any one tell me whats going wrong here.

```
TimerCapture interval=5

TimerSave interval=6
```

Here is the code can tell you the scenario:

```
Public Class Form1


    Private Sub timerCapture_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles timerCapture.Tick
        Dim bounds As Rectangle
        Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
        Dim graph As Graphics
        bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
        screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
        graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
        PictureBox1.Image = screenshot
    End Sub




    Private Sub timerSave_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles timerSave.Tick
        Me.PictureBox1.Image.Save("d:\\capture.bmp")

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ' Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized

        'Me.ShowInTaskbar = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub timerClose_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles timerClose.Tick
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub capture_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles capture_btn.Click
        Dim bounds As Rectangle
        Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
        Dim graph As Graphics
        bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
        screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
        graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
        PictureBox1.Image = screenshot
    End Sub

    Private Sub save_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save_btn.Click
        Me.PictureBox1.Image.Save("d:\\capture.bmp")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Where does your application throw the exception in the code?

Comment: Using multiple free-running timers looks like a recipe for disaster. What's the thinking behind using 3 different timers?

Comment: The reason is rather than capturing the snapshot by button I tried to do it automatically by using timer.

Comment: I hope 5 and 6 aren't your actual Timer.Interval values.  That is way too fast!

Comment: Ya its just an example bro but could you tell me how could I get the snapshots at particular interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in timerSave_Tick, if, for some reason you haven't already valued Me.PictureBox1.Image in timerCapture_Tick, it would throw NullReferenceException while trying to access to PictureBox1.Image.

Try to modify it in such way:

```
Private Sub timerSave_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles timerSave.Tick
    If(Me.PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing) Then
        Me.PictureBox1.Image.Save("d:\\capture.bmp")
    End If
End Sub
```

Anyway, you should be able to debug under Visual Studio, to see where the Exception is thrown..

Comment: Hey could you tell me how do i take snapshot of screen at particular interval because your code solved the problem but now the program goes in not responding state

Comment: I think it should be better to merge the Screenshot function with the save one. Use just one timer that will take the Screenshot AND save it to file. You could also save it without put it into a PictureBox. Moreover, try changing your timer interval to a bigger one (remember that timer interval are in MILLIseconds!)

Comment: @VighaneshGursale You wrote `"...you've solved the problem"`, which is great. Now please consider accepting this as an answer.