# VB.NET - Screen Capture with Region Selector, like Gyazo

Tags: .net, vb.net, screen

how can i make a Screenshot of a Selected Region on my Screen ?

In C# i know how to, but not in VB.Net.
I guess GDI ?

Are there some Codes ?

Thanks

Comment: Could this be what you are looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460330/screen-capture-program-in-vb-net

Comment: Just use converter to your original c# code http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/. It usually gives good results.

Comment: @KayNelson - I tried it, but i guess its not what i'm looking for :/

Comment: @IvanH - I already tried, but there was Variabels it couldnt translate

Comment: Add to question a sample. It is usually best way to get a useful answer.