# .net equivalent to form.print

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am attempting to upgrade some old vb6 projects to .net. My plan is to use the vs2005 upgrade wizard, to get to .net 2.0, fix all the bugs and then move up to vs2008, etc. One of my projects allows users to format data, on the fly, by changing x and y positions, view the new output on a form and if they like what they see, print the database to a printer with the new format.
I am having a problem with some "form properites", namely .CurrentX, .CurrentY and .Print.
In vb6 we were able to use the me.CurrentX, me.CurrentY and me.Print to format and print directly onto the form. How is this done in .net

```
  Code example:
  xpos = txtStartLeft
  YPos = txtStartTop
  'center and print Name
  xpos = (WW - Me.TextWidth(rs!name)) / 2
  Me.CurrentY = YPos
  Me.CurrentX = xpos
  Me.Print rs!name
  YPos = YPos + LineSize
  If IsNull(rs!Desc1) = True Then Exit Sub
  'format and print Desc1
  'left(temp,11) are for formatting purposes only
  Temp = rs!Desc1
  Me.Font.Bold = Mid(Temp, 9, 1)
  Me.Font.Italic = Mid(Temp, 10, 1)
  Me.Font.Underline = Mid(Temp, 11, 1)
  Me.Font.name = cboToFontName.List(CInt(Mid(Temp, 5, 2)))
  Me.Font.Size = CInt(Mid(Temp, 7, 2))
  If Left(Temp, 2) = "C " Then 'Align Center
     xpos = (WW - Me.TextWidth(Right(Temp, Len(Temp) - 11))) / 2
  ElseIf Left(Temp, 2) = "L " Then 'Align Left
     YPos = HH / 3
     xpos = txtToStartLeft + 100
  End If
  Me.CurrentY = YPos
  Me.CurrentX = xpos
  Me.Print Right(Temp, Len(Temp) - 11)
  YPos = YPos + LineSize
```

Comment: There are some examples on the MSDN ; http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72b5a038-912d-4455-929d-89eeb9984d7c/how-do-i-print-a-form-in-vbnet and how to screen shot is described in this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460330/screen-capture-program-in-vb-net

Comment: The context is very unclear but this code has been completely replaced by the Graphics class.  Which has, say, a DrawString() method that already takes the "current" arguments.  It belongs in the Paint event handler.  There are *millions* of google hits and books that show you how to do it, they are impossible to not find.

Comment: Hans, I searched the internet for 2 days to no avail. I hope with the added information you supplied, "Graphic Class",DrawString() and Paint Handler, I can find what I am looking for. Thanks for you assistance.

Comment: Preet, the example you mentioned has 2 compile errors.1) Name 'PrintDocument1' is not declared. 2) Handles clause requires a withevents varialbe defined in the containing type or one of its base types....I am trying a workaround...thanks

Comment: Public Class Form1
    Public Sub DrawStringPointF(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim drawString As [String] = "Sample Text"
        Dim drawFont As New Font("Arial", 16)
        Dim drawBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
        Dim drawPoint As New PointF(150.0F, 150.0F)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myE As PaintEventArgs
        DrawStringPointF(myE)
    End Sub
End Class 
NullReferenceException e.Graphics

Comment: how do you format code in comment?